# Testcafe: how to Switch Between multiple windows

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

i have write code for multiple windows. i.e when i click on button it will open new  window then in that window i have to do click operation .
i have used this code
const y=await ClientFunction(() => window.location.pathname)()

```
   await t.switchToWindow(f => f.url.pathname === y)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZdMj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaYdD.png)

Answer (score 1):

In general, your approach is correct.
Take a look at this sample:

```
fixture `fixture`
    .page `http://example.com`;

test(`test`, async t => {
    await t.openWindow('http://google.com');

    await t.switchToWindow(data => {
        return data.url.hostname === 'example.com';
    });

    await t.click('h1');
});
```

If it does not help, please share a sample that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: if i apply  your code it will open again another window ,but the scenario is when i click on add button in my application it will already open window.

Comment: i have used this code:  const y=await ClientFunction(() => window.location.pathname)()

    await t.switchToWindow(f => f.url.pathname === y)

Comment: i have tried the code which you have given . it is throwing error  1)  Cannot find the window specified in the action parameters.

Comment: It's very difficult to reproduce the issue using only your description. Please share an example that demonstrates the issue.